# Trouble with Inserting into a table using inner join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to insert an average value pulled from values in another table. 
I am able to calculate the average, but when it comes to inserting it into a table under the conditions , I get an error - see below.

Im pretty sure I am suppose to be using an update funcation however not sure how to implement the update with the inner join

[image]

This is the code I am using.

```
INSERT INTO TESTS (TEST_AVERAGE) 
SELECT AVG(STUDENT_SCORE )
FROM STUDENT_SCORES  
INNER JOIN TESTS
ON STUDENT_SCORES.TEST_ID = TESTS.TEST_ID AND TESTS.TEST_ID = 'TST100'
```

When I run the select statement , I can see the correct Value

[image]

The Test Table has data inserted however the Test Average is the only column awating entries and are allowed to be null

[image]

Comment: You're only declaring a value for the column `TEST_AVERAGE`, and `TEST_ID` can't be `NULL`. A column that doesn't have a value inserted into it, and doesn't have a `DEFAULT` value will have the value `NULL`. You need to provide a value for `TESTID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add TEST_ID into your VALUES list and into your SELECT stmt

```
INSERT INTO TESTS (TEST_ID, TEST_AVERAGE) 
SELECT TESTS.TEST_ID, AVG(STUDENT_SCORE )
FROM STUDENT_SCORES  
INNER JOIN TESTS
ON STUDENT_SCORES.TEST_ID = TESTS.TEST_ID AND TESTS.TEST_ID = 'TST100'
GROUP BY TESTS.TEST_ID
```

Comment: One would think that in a table called `TESTS` that `TEST_ID` is the primary key; so this woukld create duplicates and the `INSERT` would fail. But, that is an assumption.